# Como colocar um atributo como chave estrangeira e primária ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Utilizo *MySQL Workbench* e tenho que representar um *DER* no modelo físico. Me deparo com uma especialização:

```
TABELA_PESSOA       
cpf*               
nome               
sexo            

TABELA_CLIENTE  
cpf_pessoa*             
email                   
senha                   

TABELA_FUNCIONARIO  
cpf_pessoa*  
salario  
cargo
```

Como consigo fazer com que `cpf_pessoa` seja chave estrangeira (em ambas as tabelas) referente a `TABELA_PESSOA` e ao mesmo tempo sejam chaves primárias em suas respectivas tabelas?

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que você faria para declarar uma chave estrangeira em outra coluna

Comment: Acontece que eu já tentei fazer isso. Eu abri o MySQL Workbench e fiz um script bem rápido para demonstrar o meu problema (obviamente alguns tipos dos atributos não refletem a realidade, foi apenas para demonstrar): 
--Inicio create database teste; use teste; create table pessoa( cpf bigint primary key, nome varchar(40), sexo varchar(10) ); create table cliente( cpf_pessoa bigint primary key, email varchar(40), senha varchar(20), foreign key (cpf_pessoa) references pessoa(cpf) ); desc cliente; --Fim
Quando executo o "desc cliente", o atributo "cpf_pessoa" aparece apenas como chave primária